# Override observer method in child class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm stuck on this problem.
Firstly, I have a class A, that is parent class.
Class B inherits from class A.
In class A, I added observer for some notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

I fill method "appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground" with some lines of code.
In class B, I want to make changes for this handling method, so I override this method. But actually, the method in class B with the same name not called each time the notifications fire while the method in class A is called.
How can I solve this?
In method of class B, I donnot call `[super appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground];`because I want a different implementation.

EDIT: From comment below

```
- (void)appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground { 
     //-to be define 
     DEBUGLog(@"did become active"); 
     WFFogSponsorVC *fogSponsorVC = [[[WFFogSponsorVC alloc] init] autorelease]; 
     [self presentModalViewController:fogSponsorVC animated:NO]; 
}
```

I register observer in viewDidLoad method of parent class (base class), and I remove observer registration in viewWillDisappear to prevent multiple observers.

I also wonder how to remove observer registration in child class if the registration has implemented in parent class?

Comment: Can you show the method where you're registering observer and that appDidBecomeActive method?

Comment: `- (void)appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground {
    //-to be define
    DEBUGLog(@"did become active");
    WFFogSponsorVC *fogSponsorVC = [[[WFFogSponsorVC alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:fogSponsorVC animated:NO];
}`

Comment: Its better to add code to question instead of comment - here is hardly readable ;) anyway, I was more interested in that method where you're registering observer

Answer (score 1):

Notification center will notify objects that register themselves to be notified when an event of interest happens. In your case only the parent class is interested in `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification because only the parent class has been registered as the observer and not the child class. so only the parent class will be notified when the event of interest happens.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

In the above notification registration code `addObserver:self` represents parent class and not child class.

Comment: Yes,that's true so I have to add observer on child class. This is incovenient.

Comment: Yes it is :(.  Notification centre has no idea about objects and relationships between them. It just does its job of notifying object which has registered itself as an observer. So child class also has to register if it wants to be notified.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the observer in the B class. This way it will be called every time when the app becomes active.

In your class B appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground method you should call [super appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground].

Class B

```
- (void)appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground {      
    [super appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground];
    //Do your another stuff here
}
```

Class A

```
- (void)appDidBecomeActiveFromBackground {      
    //-to be define 
    DEBUGLog(@"did become active"); 
    WFFogSponsorVC *fogSponsorVC = [[[WFFogSponsorVC alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:fogSponsorVC animated:NO]; 
}
```

This way both class's code will run and you have to register the observer once.